# How to use getTimeInMillis tomorrow time on android?

Tags: android

I want get tomorrow '04:00' time use `getTimeInMillis();`

and I try this.

```
String time1 = "23:00"; // I want get 2017-02-22 23:00
String time2 = "04:00"; // I want get 2017-02-23 04:00

String[] btime1 = time1.split(":");
String[] btime2 = time2.split(":");

Calendar ctime1 = Calendar.getInstance();
ctime1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(btime1[0]));
ctime1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(btime1[1]));

Calendar ctime2 = Calendar.getInstance();
ctime2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(btime2[0]));
ctime2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(btime2[1]));

Calendar curtime = Calendar.getInstance();

Log.d(TAG, "23:00 time --->" + ctime1.getTimeInMillis());  // 1487772017952
Log.d(TAG, "04:00 time --->" + ctime2.getTimeInMillis());  // 1487703617952
Log.d(TAG, "curtime --->" + curtime.getTimeInMillis());    // 1487724197952    --> curtime is 2017-02-22 09:44
```

and I check logcat  `ctime2.getTimeInMillis();` is `2017-02-22 04:00`  time.
    but I want get tomorrow `04:00` time (2017-02-23 04:00)

```
how to get tommorow time ? 

@update
and I try   
`ctime2.getTimeInMillis() + (24*60*60*1000);`   --> 148770361795286400000 

thanks.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //current time (today)
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4); //reset to 4 am (today)
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); //add a day
```